# C++ Are there any good alternatives to global declaration of this class and singleton?

Tags: c++, class, singleton, global

How can I make a single instance of this class without singleton and how can I declare it so another class can access it without declaring it globally?

Please read the codes (especially the comments) for a better understanding:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

// The only class that will be using this class is Obj...
// There can only be a single instance of ObjManager but how can I do that
// without singleton???
class ObjManager
{
    friend class Obj;
    int i;
};

// Since I cannot think of a better way of accessing the SAME and ONLY ObjManager, I
// have decided to declare a global instance of ObjManager so every instance of
// Obj can access it.
ObjManager g_ObjManager;

class Obj
{
    friend class ObjManager;
public:
    void Set(int i);
    int Get();
};

void Obj::Set(int i) {
    g_ObjManager.i += i;
};

int Obj::Get() {
    return g_ObjManager.i;
};

int main() {
    Obj first_obj, second_obj;

    first_obj.Set(5);
    std::cout << second_obj.Get() << std::endl; // Should be 5.
    second_obj.Set(10);
    std::cout << first_obj.Get() << std::endl; // Should be 15.

    std::cin.get();
    return 0;
};
```

Comment: There is no obvious reason you don't need a God object.  God is between the chair and the monitor when you are a programmer, you can't pass the job to somebody else.

Comment: Isn't this the whole point of the Singleton pattern? Why would you want to do it without that?

Comment: With what you are doing, you can accomplish the same thing with a static member.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want all `Obj` instances to share the same `ObjManager` instance (and you don't want to use the Singleton pattern to create the `Obj`'s using the `ObjManager`), you can create a static member of `ObjManager` in `Obj`:

```
class ObjManager { ... };

class Obj
{
private:
   static ObjManager manager;
};
```

Then when you create an instance of `Obj`, it will share the same `ObjManager` with all other instances.

Answer (score 1):

Why not something like:

```
class ObjManager
{
private:
    ObjManager() {} 

public:
    static ObjManager& get() {
        static ObjectManager m;
        return m;
    }
    friend class Obj;
    int i;
};
```

Then just call `ObjManager::get` to get the reference. As a bonus, it will only be constructed if you actually use it. It's still a singleton, but it's a bit better than a global (in my opinion).